# SignalR working in browser not in app

Tags: cordova, signalr, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an app which uses signalR when I try it in the browser it works properly.
of course the connection is to an absolute URLץ

When I deploy the app to an android device it doesn't work.
I connected Chrome to do remote debug to the app's webview and I can see the network tab.

The negotiation is working and I can see result but besides that nothing works.

I assume it might be a permission\configuration issue since it works on browser.

Which steps should I take to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to make it work.
Since I'm doing my cross-domain communication using JSONP i wanted to do the same with signalR.

In my browser it worked properly but when compiled to APK and ran on device it didn't work.

changing signalR to use CORS and not jsnop solved the issue.

Comment: Hi, I have also the same problm you have. Can you help me how to implement signalR in my ionic app?

Comment: im using asp.net mvc as my backend. if you use that you need your Startup class (at App_Start) to look like this: 
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                
                map.RunSignalR();
            });

Comment: @GalZiv can you show a example, i have problem with that, i will see you solution for that, thx

Comment: I no longer work at thr company with this project. As far as i remember there were several issues: enable cross domain on server, the signalr event registration order is crutial and enable cors on ionic(cordova)  hope that helps. Feel free to ping me with more questions about it. It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

possible answer:

first of all, I'll assume that in browser means you put the client html file in a Web Server.  e.g. www.example.com/index.html

then the signalr Server hub is also in www.example.com

after you deploy, cordova put the index.html inside the Android phone or iPhone, then it becomes a cross Domain call, so you need to enable Cors to let it works!

Comment: nope. i use 'ionic serve' which create a local webserver which means i already use CORS. this is why i mentioned i use absolute url but i agree it is not that clear. further more i can see the negotiation response so it is not a connection issue (at least for its basic need to be able to create connection)

Comment: OK try this then, run in browser does not need deviceready, in phone should put codes after deviceready fires

Comment: used logging. it tries to connect after the deviceready event occurs